# How to set the value of a variable based on the generic type - Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to do something like this :-

```
Trait Hello[A]
{
  val DBAccessDAO =       A match 
                    {  case classname: Class1  => Class1DAO
                       case classname: Class2  => Class2DAO
                    } 
....

//(use appropriate DBAccessDAO to perform DAO operations

}
```

How do I do this in scala? I am not sure how to access 'A' and safely check its type.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Due to type erasure, you can't access directly the type of `T` as you want. The compiler generates a `ClassTag` type for all your classes so you can bypass the type erasure limitations. You can access the `ClassTag` implicitly:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class Hello[A : TypeTag] {
  val DBAccessDAO = typeTag[A] match {
        case tag if tag == typeTag[Class1] => ...
        case tag if tag == typeTag[Class2] => ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note also that one should use `TypeTag` instead of `ClassTag` to differentiate between, for example, `List[Class1]` vs `List[Class2]`.

Comment: Can't do that with a trait

Comment: Really good observations. Traits do not accept context bound type parameters. I change the answer to use a Class

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example that makes use of TypeTag to look up the class info at compile time

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag,typeOf}


trait Animal26
{
  val name: String
  val sound: String
}


object Tiger26 extends Animal26{

  override val name = "tiger"
  override val sound = "grrr"
}


trait Person26
{
  val title: String
  val status: String
}


object Employee26 extends Person26{

  val title = "worker"
  val status = "professional"

}


class Stack[A: TypeTag] {

  def getMyClass =
  {
    if (typeOf[A] =:= typeOf[Person26])
    Employee26
    else
     Tiger26
  }


}

object App26 extends App{

  val stack = new Stack[Person26]

  println(stack.getMyClass.toString)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeTag or something from Shapless library, but in you specific case I would propose to look into type class pattern. Getting type parameters using reflection tricks is almost always not the best solution.